# I had made a small dictionary, where i am asking user to find anything from the the dictionary. i want user to input string and numeric value

Tags: python

```
a = {"green":"hot","Rebukes":"reprimand",19: "my birthday"}
b=input("Enter the word of your choice")
print(a[b])
```

Error happens when I as a user give 19 as input to the program.
I know that input function by default takes string value and I want user to access any key from the dictionary whether it is a string or integer or float.

Comment: `input()` always return `str`. You need to convert to `int`. Also, have a look at `dict.get()` method that will prevent the `KeyError` on missing keys. Also, you can try to convert user input and handle the error if the key is not numeric, convertible t

Comment: thanks buran for your lovely answer

Comment: a = {"green":"hot", "Rebukes":"reprimand", 19: "my birthday"}
b = input("Enter the word of your choice")
c = a.get("b")
print(c)

Comment: hii buran, the last comment of mine was of the same code using get function but the output of it shows "none" after giving 19 as the input

Answer (score 0):

You read your input as a string so when you enter 19 your dictionary will look for the string key '19' instead of the integer 19.
You could test if the input is a number and if it is, cast the string to an integer:

```
a = {"green":"hot", "Rebukes":"reprimand", 19: "my birthday"}
b = input("Enter the word of your choice")
if b.isnumeric():
    b = int(b)
print(a[b])
```

However, it might be a good idea to have the dictionary keys all of the same type.

Comment: thanks philip, yes you are right